# Rounding Div corners with iFrame and Image

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube

I'm having a little problem trying to round the corners of these divs containing an image and iframe for Youtube.

I'm trying to get each individual box with the video to appear rounded even after the fade in. Here is where you can see this: [example](http://8-playerpictures.com/portfolio/#)

Whenever I add border-radius:10px; to the video-container CSS and caption-style-4 img CSS, it rounds every corner but the top right and also upon mouseover will revert back to no rounded corners briefly before appearing rounded again.

This is the CSS for the video container without rounded corners:

```
video-container {
    width: 310px;
    margin: 7px;
    height: 310px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none; float: left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

 .caption-style-4 li:hover .caption{
    opacity: 1;

}

.caption-style-4 img{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 4;
 }


.caption-style-4 img{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 4;
 }
```

This is the HTML code for one of the video containers:

```
<ul class="caption-style-4"><li>
<a href="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/Ay7Z45XTlIg? iframe=true&width=853&height=480" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" >
    <img src="http://8-playerpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/NCAA-Innovation-Summit.png" alt="NCAA Innovation Summit-Ashley Johnson"/> 
    <div class="caption">
                <div class="blur"></div>
                <div class="caption-text">
                    <h1>NCAA Innovation Summit</h1>
                    <p></p>
                </div>              
            </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Is there a reason it won't work with the iFrame? Is this just a matter of not adding it in the right places?

I appreciate all your help!

Comment: It looks like you're using a link, not an iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

On the 8-Player Pictures site, they are bypassing the normal behavior of an anchor tag using JavaScript. They have the anchor tag as a backup in case JavaScript isn't supported so it will take them to YouTube directly to see the video (This is what your markup does, so you can't apply CSS). Where JavaScript IS supported, they are creating an embedded iFrame when the anchor tag is clicked and cancelling out the normal behavior. You probably don't have that same coding, so you would want to implement that or find a different way that uses iFrames directly.

I hope that helps!